# How to get sheet name using formula excel 2007

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to get excel 2007 sheet name in a cell of that sheet using formula. I tried to Google and found this:

`=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255)`

But that does not work for excel 2007.

```
CELL("filename";A1)
```

Works but it gets the whole path.
My question is is there a way to get only a sheet name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following formula:

```
=RIGHT(CELL("filename"),LEN(CELL("filename"))-FIND("]",CELL("filename")))
```

<sup>* Workbook must be saved first!</sup>

The formula is doing this:

`RIGHT` will return the characters after a numerical amount of characters in a string.

`LEN` returns the number of characters in a string.

`FIND` returns a number based on where a string is found within a string.

So all in all, the formula is saying take away the place that the first found `]` is within the filename from the total length of the filename. We then just need the right hand portion of the filename after the numerical value we've just calculated.

Comment: @ Gareth I thing your formula won't work on Excel 2007. Should be =RIGHT(CELL("filename");LEN(CELL("filename"))-FIND("]";CELL("filename")))

Comment: This really should use 2nd parameter of `CELL`, like OP is doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can "translate" 2010 formula to 2007:
`=MID(CELL("filename";A1);FIND("]";CELL("filename";A1);1)+1;LEN(CELL("filename";A1)))`

You may thing shorter way but that one works well.